# Sql query for joining three tables

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables

### Users

```
ID || login   || name     || crypted_password  || salt
 2 || teacher1|| teacher1 || #@@EDGCH          || SDWH@##
```

### Role(main)

```
id||name
3 ||teacher
```

### Role_users

```
id || role_id || user_id
2  ||  3      ||  2
```

now from these three tables i want to fetch crypted_password and salt value of user whose role=teacher.

how can it be done!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `join` syntax to join tables according to the matching fields:

```
SELECT crypted_password, salt
FROM   users
JOIN   role_users ON users.id = role_uses.user_id
JOIN   role ON role_users.role_id = role.id
WHEN   role.name = 'teacher'
```

Answer (score 0):

Join Like this

```
SELECT U.* 
FROM USER U 
JOIN Role_Users RU ON RU.UserID = U.ID
JOIN Role R ON R.ID = RU.Role_ID
WHERE <Your Conditions here>
```

Comment: thanku @damith ,, and @vignesh!! for the help!! this worked perfectly fine!!! u people rock!!! ;) :)

Comment: @user3048066 Mark as **answer** / **Upvote** if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
select crypted_password,salt
from Users U
inner join Role_users RU on RU.user_id = U.ID
inner join Role R on R.id = RU.role_id
where R.name='teacher'
```